# Ffmpeg encoding a video with time_base Not equal to framerate does not work hardware accelerated Video Player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I have a time_base of 90000 with a frame rate of 30. I can generate a h264 video and have it work in VLC but this video does not work in a hardware accelerated web chrome player using Intel HD Graphics 530. If I change the time_base to 30 It works fine.

Note: I am changing the frame->pts appropriately to match the time_base.
Note: Video does not have audio stream

```
//header.h
AVCodecContext *cctx;
AVStream* stream;
```

Here is the non working example code

```
//source.cpp
stream->time_base = { 1, 90000 };
stream->r_frame_rate = { fps, 1 };
stream->avg_frame_rate = { fps, 1 };

cctx->codec_id = codecId;
cctx->time_base = { 1 ,  90000 };
cctx->framerate = { fps, 1 };

// ...... 
// add frame code later on timestamp are in millisecond
frame->pts = (timestamp - startTimeStamp)* 90;
```

Here is the working example code

```
//source.cpp
stream->time_base = { 1, fps};
stream->r_frame_rate = { fps, 1 };
stream->avg_frame_rate = { fps, 1 };

cctx->codec_id = codecId;
cctx->time_base = { 1 ,  fps};
cctx->framerate = { fps, 1 };

// ...... 
//  add frame code timestamp are in millisecond
frame->pts = (timestamp - startTimeStamp)/(1000/fps);
```

Any ideas on why the second example works and the first does not in the video player.